# Mahout error with Hadoop2.4.0

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, mahout

I'm trying to execute a mapreduce job using mahout 0.9 library on Hadoop 2.4. But I'm getting following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
```

So I clone the Mahout from github, checkout the branch master and recompile using:

```
mvn clean package -Dhadoop2.version=2.4.0
```

But I got another error :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Mahout Build Tools ................................ SUCCESS [1.954s]
[INFO] Apache Mahout ..................................... SUCCESS [0.589s]
[INFO] Mahout Math ....................................... SUCCESS [12.393s]
[INFO] Mahout MapReduce Legacy ........................... FAILURE [2:05.777s]
[INFO] Mahout Integration ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Examples ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Release Package ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Math Scala bindings ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Spark bindings ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Spark bindings shell ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout H2O backend ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:21.184s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Dec 14 15:40:54 CST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/120M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (job) on project mahout-mrlegacy: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive job: error in opening zip file -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :mahout-mrlegacy
```

-X error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (job) on project mahout-mrlegacy: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive job: error in opening zip file -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal       org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (job) on project mahout-mrlegacy: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive job: error in opening zip file
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive job: error in opening zip file
at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:495)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.ArchiveCreationException: Error creating assembly archive job: error in opening zip file
at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive(DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:190)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:436)
... 21 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: error in opening zip file
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:472)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.filter.ComponentsXmlArchiverFileFilter.finalizeArchiveCreation(ComponentsXmlArchiverFileFilter.java:166)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.runArchiveFinalizers(AbstractArchiver.java:884)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.createArchive(AbstractArchiver.java:908)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.archiver.AssemblyProxyArchiver.createArchive(AssemblyProxyArchiver.java:512)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive(DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:186)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:128)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoZipFileResourceCollection.getEntries(PlexusIoZipFileResourceCollection.java:53)
at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.AbstractPlexusIoArchiveResourceCollection.getResources(AbstractPlexusIoArchiveResourceCollection.java:76)
at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.proxy.PlexusIoProxyResourceCollection.getResources(PlexusIoProxyResourceCollection.java:89)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:468)
... 27 more

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :mahout-mrlegacy
```

if I should change the assembly's version? I don't know why I got this error....

Thank you!

Comment: I think that is it related to the mahout trainnb command compilation. I suggest that you try to recompile without testing -DskipTests option

Comment: To skip tests is not working. The same error...

Comment: Can you post the error with the -X option?

Comment: I add the error in question above.